# What are some specific operations for matrices, like is dot product for vectors?

Tags: matrices, vectors, operator-algebras

I read this question and the associated answer ([What is the dot product between a vector of matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521462/what-is-the-dot-product-between-a-vector-of-matrices)), and it wasn't what I am looking for.

I want to know if there are some special operations designed for bi-dimensional or multi-dimensional vectors ?

When I refer to dot product, I don't mean the equivalent for matrices, but rather an operation that deals with matrices and computes something.

Comment: Both matrix addition and matrix multiplication are defined, both taking two matrices and returning a matrix.  The determinant of a matrix is also defined, taking a single matrix and returning a number.

Answer (score 3):

There are many specific operations for matrices, usually given as a bilinear product from $M_n(K)\times M_n(K)\rightarrow M_n(K)$, like the matrix product or the Lie bracket $(X,Y)\mapsto [X,Y]=XY-YX$. Another operation is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) from
$M_{m,n}(K)\otimes M_{p,q}(K)\rightarrow M_{mp,nq}(K)$.